# Changing Slider's Height

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, windows-store-apps

I have a slider. When I set its height, the selection border changes but the slider height is still the same (22px).

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

I believe that I need to change some properties in the default style but I couldnt understand what - I want to make the height dynamic - if I change to 200 it will be 200, if I change to 158 it will be 158 and so on...

I succeed to change the height to something specific by changing the `HorizontalThumb` `Height` to specific height (changed to different height than what I set)

Comment: Why do you set such a large height for the horizontal slider?

Comment: I dont want that large height. I want 50-60px height. I am using AIO computer with 1080p resolution. I want to relieve the users with the touch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**

```xml
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="SliderRow" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1524*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Content="Mail" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <Slider Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,ElementName=SliderRow}" Style="{StaticResource MyCustomSlider}"/>
</Grid>
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

Ok, I got what you want. You want to increase the track height as well when you increase height of slider itself. Then you need to customize the slider. I replaced `{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}` with `{TemplateBinding Height}`, so when slider's height is increased the slider track will also be increased.

Style

```xml
<Style TargetType="Slider" x:Key="MyCustomSlider">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SliderBorderThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource SliderBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Thumb" x:Key="SliderThumbStyle">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbBorderThemeBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalBorder"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalBorder"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TopTickBar"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalInlineTickBar"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BottomTickBar"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LeftTickBar"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalInlineTickBar"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RightTickBar"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhiteHorizontal"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                To="1"
                                                Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlackHorizontal"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                To="1"
                                                Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhiteVertical"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                To="1"
                                                Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlackVertical"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                To="1"
                                                Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate" Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="17" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrackRect"
                            Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalDecreaseRect"
                            Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Grid.Row="1" />
                        <TickBar x:Name="TopTickBar"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                            Height="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Margin="0,0,0,2"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <TickBar x:Name="HorizontalInlineTickBar"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <TickBar x:Name="BottomTickBar"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                            Height="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Margin="0,2,0,0"
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalBorder"
                            Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb"
                        Background="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                        Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
                        DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                        Width="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhiteHorizontal"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                            StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                            StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            StrokeDashOffset="1.5"
                            Grid.RowSpan="3"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlackHorizontal"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                            StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                            StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            StrokeDashOffset="0.5"
                            Grid.RowSpan="3"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid x:Name="VerticalTemplate" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="17" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="17" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalTrackRect"
                            Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalDecreaseRect"
                            Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="2" />
                        <TickBar x:Name="LeftTickBar"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                            Width="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="0,0,2,0"
                            Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                        <TickBar x:Name="VerticalInlineTickBar"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                        <TickBar x:Name="RightTickBar"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                            Width="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Margin="2,0,0,0"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalBorder"
                            Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"                                
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                        <Thumb x:Name="VerticalThumb"
                        Background="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                        Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
                        DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
                        Width="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhiteVertical"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                            StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                            StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            StrokeDashOffset="1.5"
                            Grid.RowSpan="3"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlackVertical"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                            StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                            StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            StrokeDashOffset="0.5"
                            Grid.RowSpan="3"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage

```xml
<Slider Height="72" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="500" Style="{StaticResource MyCustomSlider}"/>
```

---

Slider's track height is assigned via standard style & resource. Its key is `SliderTrackThemeHeight` and default is 11. So you need to write below line in `App.xaml` ONLY and whenever you want to change it you can access the resource and change it.

```xml
<x:Double x:Key="SliderTrackThemeHeight">50</x:Double>
```

You can set from code behind like this.

```
Application.Current.Resources["SliderTrackThemeHeight"] = YOUR_DYNAMIC_VALUE;
```

[Slider styles and templates - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709929.aspx)

Comment: It does change the height but u didnt understand exactly what I want.
I want to see the height changing in the designer when I change the height manually by stretching it.. I dont want really specific height. I want it to stretch and fit its parent..

Comment: Still now what I want but it is getting closer. if u need to set the height and u cant let it stretch to its parent size then still no use for me (its like setting the height in the resource).

Comment: What do you mean by "parent size" ? Still what's remaining to achieve ?

Comment: Yea.. lets say the slider is in grid and the grid height is 300, I also want the slider to be 300 (in reality I dont know the height of the grid row because it depends on the resolution.

Comment: Still not 100%. The Thumb Width increased to enormous size (I want it to fit the sliders height aswell, the Thumb should be rectangle so if the height is 50, the width of the thumb should be 50 and so on..) Plus there's small gap above the slider (hopefully u notice) - it shouldnt be there if the slider match 100% of its parent.

Comment: The width is my mistake. but about the gap - not mine :P

Comment: Can you please show me an image, which represents what you want exactly ?

Comment: Nevermind, the gap is the 17px height row above the thumb. Thank you very much!!!